# AngularJS Delete function REST HTTP://1.1 500 Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, http

I am using AngularJS to delete a row via a REST API. When I click the link for the function to delete the row, I get a  Internal Server Error. I'm asking how to fix the form to get it to delete the row.

```
//CONTROLLER to delete a specific item
    countryApp.controller('DeleteLocation', function($scope, $http, $routeParams, $location) { 
        //get item info 
        var id = $routeParams.locid; 
        $scope.activePath = null; 

        $http.get('http://localhost/slimtest2/location/'+id).success(function(data) { 
          $scope.location= data; 

        });    
        //add more stuff here 
        $scope.pedelete = function(id) {    
          $http.delete('http://localhost/slimtest2/location/1/delete', id); 
        } 

    });
```

View for Deleting a Row

```
<div ng-controller="DeleteLocation"> 
   <div ng-repeat="l in location.location">  

     Are you sure you want to delete the location named: {{l.location_title }} 
    <a href="" ng-click="pedelete(l.location_id)"> Delete This</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check the API that you are using .. are you sending the url as required?

Comment: Check you API using POSTMAN. If the API is working fine it means the problem is in your APP.

Comment: I did test my API, it's working fine. I insert to the body {"location_id":"[number of item to be deleted"} it works fine. Tried to emulate it on the Angular side, so far it's not working.

Comment: I would suggest to use fiddler in order to get the exact API response and the data it is returning.

Comment: You need to understand that a Server Error 500 is related to the server, or the request you sent it, not directly with Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Internal Server error occurs when something happens wrong at server-side. Please check your server-side code/configuration are proper or not.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points to check:
1. Is your request method type "get" for a delete request as well or should it be "delete"? For this you need to check which method type your API is expecting. You may want to use `$http.delete()` instead.
2. Check your browser console/network. Are you seeing the error there? If so, work out on the error to resolve the issue. The error description should be coming what your API is sending.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's a delete method and I used the REST Client on the Mozilla Dev Browser, and it works well.

Comment: Did you try:
`$http.delete('http://localhost/slimtest2/location/'+id).success(function(data) { 
          $scope.location= data; 

        });`